# How to delete current list item with the same class name after clicking on close icon

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to delete current list item after clicking on its close icon. I'm adding list items using javascript function. Please check the image and my code for reference. Thanks in advance.

[image]

code is below:

```js
function addServices() {
  var service = $.trim($('#services').val());
  if (service != "") {
    var value = $('<li class="service-name" onclick="removeServices()">' + service + '<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" alt="Remove icon" title="Remove"></i></li>');
    $('.products-list').append(value).children(':last').hide().fadeIn(400);
  }
};

function removeServices() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 class="heading">3. Buisness Products & Services* - <span class="subheading">Enter all services that your business offers (Max 
             80 charcters)</span></h4>
<input type="text" id="services" name="tagline" maxlength="60" required="" placeholder="Enter products and services your business 
             offers." />
<input type='button' value='+ Add' id='add' onclick="addServices()" class="add" />

<ul class="products-list col-xs-12" id='list'></ul>
<div class="both"></div>
```

Thank you all genius coder on this community. Take a bow!!!

Comment: You should add your html code as welll, and maybe css, so that we can have a working snippet.

Comment: Can you please include code of your html elements too.

Comment: Yes I'm gonna include it now.

Comment: Thank you!! problem solve!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Remove unnecessary spaces you have in your `<li>` adding code.

2.You need to pass `this` in you `onclick` function and then it will work:-

```
 function addServices() {
     var service = $.trim($('#services').val());
     if (service != "") {
     //remove unnecessary spaces from below line
     var value = $('<li class="service-name" onclick="removeServices(this)">' +service + '<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" alt="Remove icon" title="Remove"></i></li>');

     $('.products-list').append(value).children(':last').hide().fadeIn(400);
   }
 };

  function removeServices(ele) {
     $(ele).parent().remove(); // or try $(ele).remove();
  };
```

***Working snippet:-***

```js
function addServices() {
   var service = $.trim($('#services').val());
   if (service != "") {
   var value = $('<li class="service-name" onclick="removeServices(this)">' +service + '<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"  alt="Remove icon" title="Remove"></i></li>');
   $('.products-list').append(value).children(':last').hide().fadeIn(400);
 }
};

function removeServices(ele) {
   $(ele).parent().remove(); // or try $(ele).remove();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">
<h4 class="heading">3. Buisness Products & Services* - <span class="subheading">Enter all services that your business offers (Max 
             80 charcters)</span></h4>
<input type="text" id="services" name="tagline" maxlength="60" required="" placeholder="Enter products and services your business 
             offers." />
<input type='button' value='+ Add' id='add' onclick="addServices()" class="add" />

<ul class="products-list col-xs-12" id='list'></ul>
<div class="both"></div>
```

Comment: @Leo  Glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 1):

Attach the listener properly using Javascript instead of as an HTML attribute (which is as bad as `eval`). Also, your current HTML string needs to be fixed - the last line needs a starting `'` (and the second to last line needs a `' +`)

You might just use a template literal instead if you find the quotes hard to deal with:

```
function addServices() {
  var service = $.trim($('#services').val());
  if (service === "") return;
  var li = $(`<li class="service-name">
    ${service}<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"
    alt="Remove icon" title="Remove"></i></li>`);
    li.click(removeServices);
  $('.products-list').append(li).children(':last').hide().fadeIn(400);
}

function removeServices() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I played a little with your code.

Here is a working snippet with comments:

```js
function addServices() {
  var service = $.trim($('#services').val());
  if (service != "") {
    var value = $('<li class="service-name">' + service + '<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" alt="Remove icon" title="Remove"></i></li>');
    $('.products-list').append(value).children(':last').hide().fadeIn(400);
  }
};

// This one is better than using the inline "onclick"
// #list is a fix element,  These are dynamic ones
// ↓                         ↓
$('#list').on('click', '.service-name .fa-times', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">
<h4 class="heading">3. Buisness Products & Services* - <span class="subheading">Enter all services that your business offers (Max 
             80 charcters)</span></h4>
<input type="text" id="services" name="tagline" maxlength="60" required="" placeholder="Enter products and services your business 
             offers." />
<input type='button' value='+ Add' id='add' onclick="addServices()" class="add" />

<ul class="products-list col-xs-12" id='list'></ul>
<div class="both"></div>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

just use on

```
$('#services').on('click','li i',function()
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

that is very simple, but you can i see the below link and change your code. 
[JsFiddle Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/44ojLqt3/)
i hope help

```
// find elements
var $list = $(".list");
var $list_item = $(".list-item i");

$list_item.each(function() {
  $(this).on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **removeServices()** try using .click()

```
$('.service-name i').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```